# No hot deployment in Jetty 9.0.6

Tags: jetty

I have set up a Jetty context by a context.xml for using virtual hosts. So my directory structure looks like this:

```
webapps
--mycontext.xml
--mycontext.war
```

Now when i upload a new war, no hot deployment occurs any more. It only happens when i modify mycontext.xml. That was not the case when i worked without a mycontext.xml.

Here is the content of mycontext.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">

 <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
 <!-- Required minimal context configuration :                        -->
 <!--  + contextPath                                                  -->
 <!--  + war OR resourceBase                                          -->
 <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
 <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
 <Set name="war"><Property name="jetty.webapps" default="."/>/mycontext.war</Set>

 <Set name="virtualHosts">
   <Array type="String">
     <Item>example.com</Item>
      <Item>www.example.com</Item>
      <Item>localhost</Item>
     <Item>127.0.0.1</Item>
   </Array>
 </Set>
</Configure>
```

Any ideas how i regain hot deployment by updating the war file?

Comment: This seems like a bug.  I filed an issue on this for you at https://bugs.eclipse.org/420944

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your mycontext.xml in the contexts directory of your server. Also you probably need to enable hot deployment in etc/jetty-deploy.xml for the war files in webapps directory as mentioned [here](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/hot-deployment.html). As you can see the configuration enables the hot deployment

```
......
 <Set name="monitoredDirName"><Property name="jetty.home" default="." />/webapps</Set>
.....
```

Following is the configuration which is working for me

jetty.home/contextx/mycontext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">

 <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
 <!-- Required minimal context configuration :                        -->
 <!--  + contextPath                                                  -->
 <!--  + war OR resourceBase                                          -->
 <!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
 <Set name="contextPath">/mycontext</Set>
 <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home"/>/webapps/mycontext.war</Set>

 <Set name="virtualHosts">
   <Array type="String">
     <Item>example.com</Item>
      <Item>www.example.com</Item>
      <Item>localhost</Item>
     <Item>127.0.0.1</Item>
   </Array>
 </Set>
</Configure>
```

Please note how I have supplied the war file name and location

```
 <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home"/>/webapps/mycontext.war</Set>
```

jetty.home/etc/jetty-deploy.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">

<!-- =============================================================== -->
<!-- Create the deployment manager                                   -->
<!-- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -->
<!-- The deplyment manager handles the lifecycle of deploying web    -->
<!-- applications. Apps are provided by instances of the             -->
<!-- AppProvider interface.  Typically these are provided by         -->
<!-- one or more of:                                                 -->
<!--   jetty-webapps.xml       - monitors webapps for wars and dirs  -->
<!--   jetty-contexts.xml      - monitors contexts for context xml   -->
<!--   jetty-templates.xml     - monitors contexts and templates     -->
<!-- =============================================================== -->
<Configure id="Server" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server">

    <Call name="addBean">
      <Arg>
        <New id="DeploymentManager" class="org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager">
          <Set name="contexts">
            <Ref id="Contexts" />
          </Set>
          <Call name="setContextAttribute">
            <Arg>org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern</Arg>
            <Arg>.*/servlet-api-[^/]*\.jar$</Arg>
          </Call>


          <Call id="webappprovider" name="addAppProvider">
          <Arg>
            <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider">
              <Set name="monitoredDirName"><Property name="jetty.home" default="." />/webapps</Set>
              <Set name="defaultsDescriptor"><Property name="jetty.home" default="." />/etc/webdefault.xml</Set>
              <Set name="scanInterval">1</Set>
              <Set name="extractWars">true</Set>
            </New>
          </Arg>
        </Call>

        </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>
</Configure>
```

With this configuration, when I put a modified mycontext.war in webapps, jetty happily 
redeploys the war.

Comment: Does not work for me. As far as i can see, the only difference to my configuration is the way you provide the war-path. I have tried that, but jetty.home/webapps and jetty.webapps should be equal.

My workaround is to touch the mycontext.xml during the automated distribution process. That's sufficient for now.